# clapper live stream player error with vue js

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to build live stream player

i tried Calppr but it's not work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/clapper/clapper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerElement = document.getElementById("player-wrapper");

var player = new Clappr.Player({
 source: 'Here is my source',
 poster: 'http://clappr.io/poster.png',
 mute: true,
 height: 360,
 width: 640
});

player.attachTo(PLAYERELEMENT);

</script>
```

the Error is that  **Clappr Not Defiend**
i tried use CDN also but the same error again

can someone help me or lead me to another player that supports  **VUE JS**

Answer (score 0):

In Vue with your code Your player init code should be in `mounted()` of component containing `#player-wrapper`. Also make sure that your clappr import is in html template not in *.vue file of component. Or imported in script section of *.vue like this: `import Clappr from 'clappr'`. And make `npm i clappr`